# If the given sets are pairwise disjoint then.....

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $X$ is a set containing $n$ elements. Let us define set $P_i$ denote a subset of $X$.  Let us choose $m$ subsets of $X$ such that $P_i\cap P_j=\phi$ for $i\neq j$ and $i,j=1,2,\cdots,m$.

Now from the above statements can the following be concluded:
$$P_i\cap P_j=\varnothing \implies P_1\cap P_2\cap P_3\cdots\cap P_m=\varnothing $$

Comment: $P_1\cap P_2 \cap \cdots \subseteq P_1\cap P_2$

Comment: $(P_1\cap P_2)=\emptyset$ does indeed imply that $(P_1\cap P_2)\cap P_3\cap \dots \cap P_m = \emptyset \cap P_3\cap \dots \cap P_m = \emptyset$ since the empty set intersected with anything... in particular $P_3,P_4,\dots$ will again be empty.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : Proove and apply the following to well choosen sets : $A \cap B\cap C \subset A\cap B$

Comment: Thanks for the hint